# $_SERVER[QUERY_STRING] copying itself

Tags: html, sql

This is the part of the code for paging(when you see page 1,page 2...at the bottom).The **$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]** is used to copy what was searched on previous page so that page number 2 displays results for same query.

The problem is that on page 2 the "query string" is added with page number *&page=2* so when you click for page 3 the **$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]** copies the query(which i need to be copied,eg. *?search=salad*)and the page number(which is unnecessary),it looks like this *&page=2&page=3*

Is there any good way to do this?...it would be nice if something could change only the number of page instead copying whole word.

```
<a href='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]?start=$back'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>PREV</font></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = http_build_query(array('page' => $num) + $_GET);
printf('<a href="%s?%s">Prev</a>', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $query);
```

This uses the `$_GET` array, which contains all the values of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` in a neat array, "overwrites" the `page` value of that array, then re-assembles it into a URL-encoded query string.